Issue with Hadoop Resource , Node manager , unable to start them
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastClassEmitter.<init>(FastClassEmitter.java:67)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastClass$Generator.generateClass(FastClass.java:72)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:216)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastClass$Generator.create(FastClass.java:64)
        at com.google.inject.internal.BytecodeGen.newFastClass(BytecodeGen.java:204)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethod$FastClassProviderMethod.<init>(ProviderMethod.java:256)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethod.create(ProviderMethod.java:71)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethodsModule.createProviderMethod(ProviderMethodsModule.java:275)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethodsModule.getProviderMethods(ProviderMethodsModule.java:144)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethodsModule.configure(ProviderMethodsModule.java:123)
        at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:340)
        at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:349)
        at com.google.inject.AbstractModule.install(AbstractModule.java:122)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletModule.configure(ServletModule.java:52)
        at com.google.inject.AbstractModule.configure(AbstractModule.java:62)
        at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:340)
        at com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:110)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorShell$Builder.build(InjectorShell.java:138)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:104)
        at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:96)
        at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:73)
        at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:62)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.WebApps$Builder.build(WebApps.java:417)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.WebApps$Builder.start(WebApps.java:465)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager.startWepApp(ResourceManager.java:1275)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager.serviceStart(ResourceManager.java:1384)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.start(AbstractService.java:194)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager.main(ResourceManager.java:1585)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @351d00c0
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.throwInaccessibleObjectException(AccessibleObject.java:391)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:367)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:315)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.checkCanSetAccessible(Method.java:203)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.setAccessible(Method.java:197)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$2.run(ReflectUtils.java:56)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:319)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils.<clinit>(ReflectUtils.java:46)
        ... 29 more
2024-04-07 19:20:25,297 INFO resourcemanager.ResourceManager: Transitioning to standby state
2024-04-07 19:20:25,297 INFO resourcemanager.ResourceManager: Transitioned to standby state
2024-04-07 19:20:25,299 INFO resourcemanager.ResourceManager: SHUTDOWN_MSG:


What Java version are you using? Last I checked, hadoop doesn't support over Java 11
